# How to translate Perl's match and substitution operators to Python?

Tags: python, perl

I am trying to translate a few directives for regular expressions from Perl to Python.

I am specifically looking for being able to translate the following three directives:

```
  while ($string =~ s/A/B/g) {
  }


  $string =~ s/A/B/g;

  if ($string =~ m/a/)
  {
       ## do something
  }
```

It seems like you can't use the usual s// and m// syntax that Perl and other unix tools have. Is it really true, and I would have to look deeply into regexp analysis in Python, or is there some easy way to translate these directives?

Comment: Just read the Python [`re`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html#module-re) docs. You'll basically need to replace the `s///` and `m///` directives with I think `re.sub` and `re.match`, I think (but I don't know perl so you should check this for yourself).

Comment: Wrong question. The question you should be asking yourself is "how do I match using regular expressions in Python" and "how do I perform substitutions based on regular expressions in Python". From there, it's easy to see the way forward: Googling would surely lead you to docs and examples.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). With `re`, you can do things like this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z]')
if pattern.search(string):
    print "string contains a capital letter"
```

You can also do substitutions using the `sub` method instead of `search`.